# Django : when client request http methods that are not defined in the view class

Tags: django, http, view

I am now learning django rest framework library. And when I read the tutorial I suddenly curious about that what will happen if client request http methods that are not defined in the view class. For example If I write the code like below

```
from snippets.models import Snippet
from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


class SnippetList(APIView):
    """
    List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

In this case I define the "get" and "post" methods in the View class. what if client request the "put" or "delete" methods than what happens? I read the django docs and it saids View class dispatch the http method by using dispatch(). But what is happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at the source [on Github](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py). The dispatch method checks which HTTP verb was used, and calls the appropriate function, or returns `405 - Method not allowed` status code when the verb is not valid/expected (`http_method_not_allowed` is a django built-in method in the base `View` class that just returns the `405` status code).

The relevant portion is pasted below:

```
# Get the appropriate handler method
if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
    handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(),
                      self.http_method_not_allowed)
else:
    handler = self.http_method_not_allowed

response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Essentially the same thing is done in django's own views (`dispatch` in `django.views.generic.View`):

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Try to dispatch to the right method; if a method doesn't exist,
    # defer to the error handler. Also defer to the error handler if the
    # request method isn't on the approved list.
    if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
        handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed)
    else:
        handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
  return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

---

If you're ever developing with django's own view classes, ["Classy Class-Based Views"](http://ccbv.co.uk/) is a very helpful resource.

Comment: so if client request "put" or "delete" http methods in my example, it will return error page?

Comment: Yes, unless you define those methods, it will return an error.

Comment: finally i understand Thanks!! :)